# pyav / Libav / ffmpeg disable B frames

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, h.264, libav, pyav

I am using `pyav` (python wrapper for `libav`) to ingest an H264 video stream. Is there an option to disable B-frames?
I think the same question would apply to `libav` and `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `skip_frame` option of the codeccontext should be set with value `bidir` or constant `AVDISCARD_BIDIR` (if assigning directly) to skip bidirectional frames.

Comment: Does it mean that the receiver will simply discard the B-frames or does it mean that the sender will not send B-frames? In other words, as a receiver, will I simply discard information or will I ask the sender to encode the data it sends me without using B-frames (using other compression methods / encoding options )?

Comment: The decoder will receive them but not decode.

Comment: So this will lead to a lower quality and possible loss of information, right?

Comment: Loss of info, yes. Lower quality, no. Unless a preserved frame references a discarded frame, the decoded result is the frame.